# Cannot use End argument within Else statement in Print() function

Tags: python, printing, conditional-statements

I just started using Python and learned the 'end' argument and the 'print if'.
However, I do not understand why I cannot use both the argument 'end' in the else statement.

```
for row in parkingLot:
    for val in row:
        print(val, end = '\t' if val < PLen else val, end = '\n')
```

If I try to do this I get the following syntax error:

```
print(val, end = '\t' if val < PLen else val, end = '\n')
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

I have also tried with parenthesis but it also does not work.

I am currently using if statements with more than one print but I was wondering which is the better way to do it in Python. (I need to print a matrix separating the elements with a '/t' and the rows with a '/n'. But I should not have a '/t' after the last element of each row. The same for the '\n' after the last line.

Comment: Type out a specific example of what output you would expect for a given input.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to use `'\t'` if the value is smaller than `PLen` and `'\n'` otherwise.

The correct ternary expression for that is

```
print(val, end='\t' if val < PLen else '\n')
```

Currently you are supplying the `end` keyword argument twice (which is an error). `, end = '\n'` is not part of your `if/else` statement.